# how to show the contacts using AutoCompleteTextView android?

Tags: android, contacts, autocompletetextview, android-cursor

i want to show contacts using AutoCompleteTextView  in my application. I googled and using some code from stack overflow but some times it is not working well and some times it is crashing too. Please any one help me in this.

custcontview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"

    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"

    card_view:contentPadding="2dp">

<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:weightSum="2">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ccontName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ccontNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/ccontName"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:layout_weight="1"
       android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ccontType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/ccontNo"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textColor="#A5000000"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

mianfragment.java:

```
 AutoCompleteTextView mobile_prepaid_mobilenum_edttxt;
   private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> mPeopleList;
```

oncreate:

```
mPeopleList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
mobile_prepaid_mobilenum_edttxt = (AutoCompleteTextView) lay.findViewById(R.id.mobile_prepaid_mobilenum_edttxt);
        new Task1().execute();
        mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), mPeopleList, R.layout.custcontview ,new String[] { "Name", "Phone" , "Type" }, new int[] { R.id.ccontName, R.id.ccontNo, R.id.ccontType });

        mobile_prepaid_mobilenum_edttxt.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mobile_prepaid_mobilenum_edttxt.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View arg1, int index, long arg3) {
                Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) av.getItemAtPosition(index);
                String name = map.get("Name");
                String number = map.get("Phone");
                mobile_prepaid_mobilenum_edttxt.setText(number);
            }
        });
}
 public void PopulatePeopleList()
    {

        mPeopleList.clear();

        Cursor people = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        while (people.moveToNext())
        {
            String contactName = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            String contactId = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String hasPhone = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

            if ((Integer.parseInt(hasPhone) > 0))
            {

                // You know have the number so now query it like this
                Cursor phones = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,
                        null, null);
                while (phones.moveToNext()) {

                    //store numbers and display a dialog letting the user select which.
                    String phoneNumber = phones.getString(
                            phones.getColumnIndex(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                    String numberType = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));

                    Map<String, String> NamePhoneType = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    NamePhoneType.put("Name", contactName);
                    NamePhoneType.put("Phone", phoneNumber.replace("-",""));

                    if(numberType.equals("0"))
                        NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Work");
                    else
                    if(numberType.equals("1"))
                        NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Home");
                    else if(numberType.equals("2"))
                        NamePhoneType.put("Type",  "Mobile");
                    else
                        NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Other");

                    //Then add this map to the list.
                    mPeopleList.add(NamePhoneType);
                }
                phones.close();
            }
        }
        people.close();
    getActivity(). startManagingCursor(people);


    }


    class Task1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {
            //Record method
            PopulatePeopleList();



            return "name";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }
    }
```

ERROR:

```
 AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
        Process: com.reload.reload, PID: 17564
        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ContentResolver android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getContentResolver()' on a null object reference
        at com.reload.reload.activity.MobileFragment.PopulatePeopleList(MobileFragment.java:1034)
        at com.reload.reload.activity.MobileFragment$Task1.doInBackground(MobileFragment.java:1087)
        at com.reloadapp.reload.activity.MobileFragment$Task1.doInBackground(MobileFragment.java:1076)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: From where are you calling this? Can you include that code also?

Comment: initialization for  `mobile_prepaid_mobilenum_edttxt` like `mobile_prepaid_mobilenum_edttxt= (AutoCompleteTextView) findviewById(R.id.mobile_prepaid_mobilenum_edttxt)`

Comment: @kartheeki j pass the Context from calling the method and use context.getContentResolver() to avoid null pointer

Comment: in oncreate i am calling  new Task1().execute(); (asynk task ). i intilaized mobile_prepaid_mobilenum_edttxt  too

Comment: check [this](http://pastebin.com/yNfYDhjg) code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are trying to `getContentResolver()` from `getActivity()`. So basically your fragment is **not** attached to the activity. This may happen in two scenarios:

1. Either your activity is destroyed: So put a null check on `getActivity()` before calling `getContentResolver()`
2. Or fragment's `onAttach()` hasn't been called yet: So call the method after `onAttach()` has been called.

According to discussion in comments:

```
    class Task1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private Context context;

        public Task1(Context context){
          this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {
            //Record method
            PopulatePeopleList(context);



            return "name";
        }
    }
```

Now in you this context in your `PopulatePeopleList()` method.

```
public void PopulatePeopleList(Context context)
{

    mPeopleList.clear();

    Cursor people = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: i am calling that asynk task in attach method. but again getting same eerror

Comment: Try passing the context in constructor. Look into the edited answer.

Comment: Okay, check if `context` is null or not on `onAttach(Context context)`

Comment: sorry...is it right or wrong ?     new Task1(context).execute();?

Comment: yes, it is right. And where are you getting this `context` from?

Comment: MobileFragment extends Fragment { Context context;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104836/discussion-between-rohit-arya-and-kartheeki-j).